# Flutter layout using grid system

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to layout in Flutter using grid system. Having something similar to [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) might be nice.

I'd like my rows to contain 4 columns with fixed spaces(gutters) between the columns. (Gutters should have same size, regardless of screen width).

And I'd like to have at least some way of saying that the widget should be N columns width, starting from `i` column.

So final api can be something like these:

```dart
GridRow(
  gutter: 16,
  columnsCount: 4,
  children: [
    GridColumn(child:SomeWidget, width:3, begin:2),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is already a package that fulfills all your needs, it is the [StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-readme-tab-).

It is not exactly the syntax you described, but the functionality should be greater or the same. You can add the gutters by setting `mainAxisSpacing` and `crossAxisSpacing`, set the column (or row, depending on the orientation) count by using `crossAxisCount`.

To specify the space which is used by the child, you define a `staggeredTiles` list, in which each `StaggeredTile` represents the child of the same index.

It is **not exactly** the same as the Bootstrap grid, but it comes close enough.

---

I've put together a super slim example:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StaggeredGridView.count(
          mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8.0, 
          crossAxisCount: 12,
          staggeredTiles: [
            StaggeredTile.count(6, 6),
            StaggeredTile.count(4, 1),
            StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
            StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
          ],
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('6,6')
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('4,1')
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('2,2')
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text('2,2')
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The only issues, is that items and positions are separated. If you need to add a new item, you need to insert in into both lists. But I can use it and create widget with better api.

Comment: Well you can simply create wrapper method like you said, hope this solves your question :)